# Can IXMLDOMElementPtr pElement->text = "..." fail?

Tags: c++, msxml

Pseudo code is as the following:

```
IXMLDOMElementPtr pElement;
pElement = pXMLDom->createElement("...");
pElement->text = "..."; // My question is can this step fail (such as because of memory restrain)?
```

More, please help me to understand the "=" operator's internal work principle! I am familiar with C, but a newbie of C++/Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  "=" operator's internal work principle is based on specific Microsoft C++ extensions, and as nothing to do with the legacy C++ operator overloading.

See [property (C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx)

> When the compiler sees a data member declared with this attribute on
>   the right of a member-selection operator ("." or "->"), it converts
>   the operation to a get or put function, depending on whether such an
>   expression is an l-value or an r-value.

When you use `#import` to import the COM definitions from a DLL (as a `MSXML?.DLL`), a TLH file (a C++ header) is created, which reflects the content of the Type Library associated with the DLL.

In that TLH you will find a declaration for a struct `IXMLDOMNode`, inheriting from `IDispatch`, with the lines:

```
__declspec(property(get=Gettext,put=Puttext))
    _bstr_t text;
```

The `Gettext` and `Puttext` methods are defined in a TLI file (inlined functions), generated during the import.

The `Puttext` methods is:

```
inline void IXMLElement::Puttext ( _bstr_t p ) {
    HRESULT _hr = put_text(p);
    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
}
```

The `put_text` method is a raw call through the interface pointer, and, as always for that kind of calls, returns a `HRESULT`. So, Yes, in theory, this step CAN fail.